# change the unique names before the uplouad

Tags: dropzone.js

I am using dropzone for file upload on laravel framework, how I can upload pictures with a specific name, not the unique generated name this is my code :
controller:

```
public function dropzone(Request $request){
    $file = $request->file('file');
    file::create([
        'title' => $file->getClientOriginalName(),
        'description' => 'Upload with dropzone.js',
        'path' => $file->store('public/storage')
    ]);
}
```

resultat : 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3G3k.png)

I wanna change the filename before the upload

sorry for my very bad English